# iFFT and extracting dw

Tags: fourier-transform, python, dft, ifft

I have a trivial fourier transform question.  I have a correlation function, C(t), with complex components in the time-domain, and dt.  I would like it in the frequency domain, C(w), like from Numerical Recipes:

[image]

I believe this involves an inverse fourier transform and grid-shifting.  I know numpy iFFT divides by sequence length, while numpy FFT is normal fourier transform.  Knowing this, how can I verify Parseval's theorem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073508/parsevals-theorem-doesnt-work-with-ifft)?

In python:

> c_w_num = np.fft.ifft(np.fft.ifftshift(c_t))

As a sanity check, grid-shifting gives me back the original c_t:

> c_t_num = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(c_w_num)) == c_t

So, I have dt, but I cannot figure out how to get the correct w, or dw.

For example, when I use the formula:

> 2.0*np.pi/(time_final - time_initial)

The dw generated does not give me something that satisfies Parseval's theorem.  Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?  Does C(w) generated with iFFT not satisfy Parseval's (below)?  Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perceval's theorem is satisfied with you apply scale factor of $1/\sqrt(N)$ for both the forward and inverse transform. I.e.

If
$$X(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x(n) e^{-j2\pi\frac{kn}{N}}$$

then

$$x(n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x(n) e^{j2\pi\frac{kn}{N}}$$

and

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}|x(n)|^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}|X(k)|^2 $$

Comment: Thank you!  I realized that iFFT in python automatically divides by N.  So I think, actually, to fix it for DFT it is:
np.sum(np.abs(c_t)**2)
np.sum(np.abs(c_w)**2) * N

Is that correct way to think about it?

Comment: There are many different ways to think about. You can scale the energy one or the other domain or write  wrapper around the DFT that implements your scaling of choice